# Filling back & front of text with different colors

Tags: modeling, rendering, color

[image]

Hi

Im trying to make something similar to the image above,

How can I color front and back with two different colors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to add to @Hiserod's answer (and since I already made the gif).
To combine two colors, simply use it as a factor in MixRGB node.

[image]

**Bonus edit:**
To use a different texture on either side, you can use the following setup:

[image]
[image]

Comment: And a bonus question: Is the rotating text shown from above or from below?

Comment: Asking the real questions! XD

Comment: Perhaps it depends on how you define "above" and "below" and whether the text is upside down in this imaginary space! Also, what is the orientation of the camera? I'm voting to close this question as needing clarification. hahaha

Comment: Its shown from the inside

Comment: anyways I appreciate your help! it worked :)

Comment: @HISEROD (Ooops, didn't mean to steal that green checkmark like that, sorry)

Comment: Not a problem! Your answer is good and thorough.

Comment: Thanks, looks good.