# Is there a way to write along a shape?

Tags: path

I´m making this scene by Space Jam and wanted to know how I could make the name of the planet orbiting around it.
Thanks!!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). If you need editable text, I'd use a Curve Modifier with a bezier circle [like here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214948/78972) :).

Answer (score 5):

1. add text
2. object -> convert to mesh
3. add sphere
4. add curve -> circle
5. add modifier "curve" to text
6. choose "circle" from 3)
7. animate location x of text

result, if you rotate the beziercircle a bit:

[image]

better explanation by video tutorial: https://youtu.be/tcKOR9TZHcA (please be patient - my internet is not that fast - is should be uploaded in 30 mins)

Comment: Hey :). No need to convert to mesh, you can keep the text editable

Comment: ah ok...learnt again something! thanx!

Comment: I don´t know why but my text looks all warped in the center of the circle when I selected it on the curve modifier :(

Comment: Please provide your blend file - then I can help u